# What is a .clientrc file?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

You can find a mention of it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide
however without any explanation. I couldn't find information about it by googling.

What is the purpose of a `.clientrc` file?

Comment: I think that might simply be an example, rather than an actual convention.

Comment: @Gama11 thanks you confirmed my mind about it. I think they used it simply to demonstrate how to make a file watcher.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, ".clientrc" was just chosen as an example file name.

If you google `site:code.visualstudio.com clientrc`, that page is the only search result. And googling `site:github.com/microsoft/vscode "clientrc"`, all the results are about example code (and most are about that example code specifically).

The `.*rc` file name pattern is a common convention for application-specific configuration files. There's [a baeldung article on it](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/rc-files#:%7E:text=rc%20Configuration%20Files,be%20a%20whole%20operating%20system.):

> Names including *rc* often signify files or directories of files with code. Specifically, this code consists of commands that are meant to run when a program is executed. Indeed, that program can be an application, but it can also be a whole operating system.
>
> Because of this, the original rc affix and extension both meant “run commands”. In particular, a widely accepted source of the term is the Compatible Time-Sharing System (CTSS)